ARIMA Hyper-parameter values for different sets of test data
I am building a monthly ARIMA forecasting model. The data I have is from last Sept, (09-2023) until May this year (05-2024). I built an ARIMA model after grid search using itertools product by taking training from Sept to March and test set April and May 2024, I got good accuracy. but when I use the same hyper-parameter (p, d, q) values for a different set, test set March and April and training from Sept to Feb, the accuracy takes a huge hit.
I have faced this situation previously even when I had 3 years data, for a particular training-test set, one set of p, d and q values give good accuracy, but the same p, d and q values give not so good accuracy for a different training-set in the same data.
In my present scenario, I can determine the accuracy as I have a test data, but if I run the ARIMA model into the future, I wouldn't be having a test data to check my accuracy and the business would have to depend on the forecast numbers of the model.
Can someone please let me know how to build ARIMA model by using same p, d and q values across different times along the temporal data.
